# WPF UserControl on parent changed event

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have an app where I have a main window that can contain other docked/attached windows.  Right now, when my user control loads I get its parent using Window.GetWindow.  This returns a reference to the main window, which is fine.  However, when I undock/detach the child window that the user control is on, the parent changes.

There are a number of parent window events that the user control needs to listen for.  I couldn't find any way for the user control to be notified when the parent changes.  It looks like ParentChanged/OnParentChanged do not exist for System.Windows.Controls.UserControl.

Is there any way my user control can be notified when its parent changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the Loaded and Unloaded events are what you need. They should also be called when the parent changes but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score -3):

Use protected override sub onparentchange

```
 check is parent not nothing
```

If true you can adhandle parent_onmouseup

Addressof event you created