# Parent changed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, parent-child, frameworkelement

is there a way to be notified when the visual parent of a FrameworkElement changes, without overriding the OnVisualParentChanged method, just by using events?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159419/wpf-usercontrol-on-parent-changed-event) is the idea to use the "Loaded" event but this doesn't seem to be safe.

Is there an event that definitively fires when the the visual parent changes/changed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to do exactly, but I often use the IsVisibleChanged event if I need something to wait until everything is finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat to do with `OnVisualParentChanged`.  In the [FrameworkElement.cs](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement@cs/1305600/FrameworkElement@cs) implementation, it does `private void TryFireInitialized()`, which in turn will call `protected virtual void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)`, so you could hook in there.

It does depend on what information you need to know.  As far as I can tell, the only place to get notified that the parent is changing AND be able to access the old parent is OnVisualParentChanged (the old parent is passed in as the parameter). Otherwise any other place to hook in you will only be able to access the new parent, as it has already been changed.

You may also want to investigate some classes that inherit FrameworkElement and see if they expose any additional properties or methods that could help you.

Comment: `TryFireInitialized()` only fires `OnInitialized` one time.

Comment: @user1574054 you are absolutely correct, thanks for catching that one

Answer (score 3):

In my tests Loaded Unloaded do get fired when parent changes so I would say it's safe to reply on them. 
But, as mentioned before you can only access the old parent if you hook OnVisualParentChanged (by the time _Unloaded is called VisualParent is already null)
Overriding OnVisualParentChanged is pretty simple if that was your concern.

```
    void _Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoSmthng();
    }

    void _Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoSmthngElse();
    }

    protected override void OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
    {
        DoSmthngOther();

        // Call base class to perform standard event handling. 
        base.OnVisualParentChanged(oldParent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently got into a situation where I really needed to know when an arbitrary element got its parent (an element that I did not create, so I had no access to overriding methods). I put together a dirty hack that, while it may not be "safe", does totally work.

The annoying thing is that `Visual` actually *does* have a `VisualAncestorChanged` event! Which does exactly what we want: gets fired right when a parent changes. ...The only problem is it's `internal`, so you have to go into [the WPF source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Visual.cs,5df1186822b6f164) to see it. Luckily, with reflection, things like access modifiers become more like suggestions.

Here's the class I built to hook into that internal event. The class exposes a public event that you can handle normally, which gets triggered by the internal event firing.

```vbnet
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Raises an event when the visual parent of a <see cref="Visual"/> changes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class VisualAncestorWatcher
        Implements IDisposable

        Public Sub New(Visual As Visual)
            Me.Visual = Visual

            Dim HandlerType = InternalVisualAncestorChangedEvent.EventHandlerType
            Dim Ctor = HandlerType.GetConstructor({GetType(Object), GetType(IntPtr)})
            Dim HandlerMethod = [GetType].GetMethod("InternalVisualAncestorChangedHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
            CreatedDelegate = Ctor.Invoke({Me, HandlerMethod.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer})
            InternalVisualAncestorChangedEvent.GetAddMethod(True).Invoke(Visual, {CreatedDelegate})
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property Visual As Visual
        Private CreatedDelegate As [Delegate]

        Private Sub InternalVisualAncestorChangedHandler(sender As Object, e As Object)
            RaiseEvent VisualAncestorChanged(sender, New AncestorChangedEventArgs(e))
        End Sub

        Public Event VisualAncestorChanged As EventHandler(Of AncestorChangedEventArgs)

        Private Shared _InternalVisualAncestorChangedEvent As Reflection.EventInfo
        Public Shared ReadOnly Property InternalVisualAncestorChangedEvent As Reflection.EventInfo
            Get
                If _InternalVisualAncestorChangedEvent Is Nothing Then _InternalVisualAncestorChangedEvent = GetType(Visual).GetEvent("VisualAncestorChanged", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                Return _InternalVisualAncestorChangedEvent
            End Get
        End Property

#Region "IDisposable"
        Private disposedValue As Boolean

        Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
            If Not disposedValue Then
                If disposing Then
                    InternalVisualAncestorChangedEvent.RemoveMethod.Invoke(Visual, {CreatedDelegate})
                End If

                disposedValue = True
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
            ' Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(disposing As Boolean)' method
            Dispose(disposing:=True)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
        End Sub
#End Region
    End Class

    Public Class AncestorChangedEventArgs
        Public Sub New(internalArgs As Object)
            Ancestor = internalArgs.Ancestor
            OldParent = internalArgs.OldParent
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property Ancestor As DependencyObject
        Public ReadOnly Property OldParent As DependencyObject
    End Class
```

Now, I am obliged to warn that this code **IS NOT SAFE** and **MAY BREAK IN THE FUTURE**. Because the event I'm hooking into isn't public, Microsoft is not under any requirements to keep it there. The name could technically change, or the entire internal implementation could be changed, and then this code would suddenly start throwing errors.

On the other hand, we're talking about some very fundamental parts of WPF here. I'd be surprised if it changed, so I'm willing to take that risk in the project I wrote this for.